# Does updating CentOS minor version enable you to update software to newer level?

Tags: centos, package-management

I've been hearing rumors like this:

1. if you don't update your CentOS minor version, such as from 6.5 to 6.9, some packages is not going to get updates from `yum update`.

is this true?

2. If I have to update to the newest minor version, say `6.9` currently, is the following approach "minimal viable"?

( **I don't want to update any other software unless absolute unecessary. Effectively I'm asking that if this minimal upgrade would enable me to upgrade any specific software to the newest available version.**)

> remove other `.repo` file, and put `enabled=0` in the [updates] section and [extras] section in the
>   `CentOS-Base.repo` file, ensure the [base] section to have `enabled=1`, then do `yum update`

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT You're right, backups are essential, but even if backups are in place, nobody wants uncessary rollback, do they? so I'm trying to move as cautious as I can here by asking the 'minimal viable' question.

Comment: Did you ever get a 100% working solution for this yet? I only ask because I recently upgraded a CentOS 7 to the latest kernel version and I believe with this method you can get explicit per whatever version major and minor that's published. Afterwards I just updated a parameter line value in the grub file, etc. rebooted, and viola, it booted to latest kernel I installed by default. I then tested functionality or other critical packages and only needed to yum update one and add a parameter to the fstab for an auto-mount issue. Happy to share initial resources if you're interested.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Did you delete your answer? And btw my question was asking about how to update specific package to the newest, across the OS minor version boundary, have you done it?

Comment: Yes, I did have an answer I deleted as I wasn't sure I understood the question 100% clearly and I didn't want to state wrong for any future readers that may stumble upon your post. I will need to test this out and do more research I suppose as I'm not sure if I have done this or not. You can boot CentOS to any kernel version and have multiple and set one as the default but choose any upon a reboot. I don't think this is too hard to test. What specific "package" are you working with here that you question? Any in particular or what. I should be able to do some test runs.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT my scenarios requires that unecessary reboot be avoided in the same way that yum update does not require a reboot.

Comment: Without knowing the specific package you need or want to do this with, it's hard to say with 100% accuracy. Rather than tricking yum though, perhaps this is an instance where explicitly downloading (or copying from another source) using rpm is justified.  Perhaps you just need to use that tool rather than yum to get the job done in this case. I know you gave out the bounty but I don't see an answer that was accepted so I thought about this post and thought I'd follow up after I did the latest kernel update on CentOS 7 in my case. Good luck but I'm happy to do further testing if you want.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT  RPMs are just too much of a hassle, I wanted to keep it easy to use all in the same time achieve the exact goal oof enabling newest update for one software. thanks for the tab-keeping though, this probably not gonna get solved in a while

Answer (score 3):

It is true that currently CentOS have gone to
[point releases](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-6e2c3746ec45ac3142917466760321e868f43c0e).
As the link says :

> The CentOS Project provides updates or other changes ONLY for the **latest version of each major branch**. Thus, if the latest minor version of CentOS-6 is version 6.6 then the CentOS Project only provides updated software for this minor version in the 6 branch. If you are using an older minor version than the latest in a given branch, then you are missing security and bugfix updates.

What this means is that for old minor releases no updates are provided,
so what you might as well disable all the yum repositories by adding
`enabled=0` (or changing the `enabled=1` to `0`) to each of the [...] sections of the files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

Nevertheless, older minor branches can still be found in the
[CentOS vault](http://vault.centos.org/),
so you are not stuck if you have not kept up with the current minor release.
You do not have to go through the vault in sequence, as the above document also
says :

> Any minor version is just a snapshot with previous updates, plus the latest batch of new upstream updates, **rolled into a new [base] repo** with an initially empty [updates] repo.

See also the post
[How do I keep Centos at version 6.3?](https://serverfault.com/questions/490330/how-do-i-keep-centos-at-version-6-3).

---

To instruct yum to install a specific version from the repository :

1. Modify the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and change all paths
   to point to `baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/VERSION/...`.
2. List all available versions in the repository of your package using
   the `--showduplicates` flag.
   For example for the available versions of the GD extension for PHP:

   ```
   # yum --showduplicates list php-gd
   ```
3. Once you know the full name of the version to install, specify
   the package name with the version, for example :

   ```
   # yum install php-gd-5.2.6
   ```

References :

- [Get yum to install a specific package version](https://www.zulius.com/how-to/yum-install-specific-package-version/)
- [How can I instruct yum to install a specific version of package X?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x)
- [How to Install Particular Package Version in CentOS and Ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-particular-package-version-in-centos-ubuntu-debian/)
- [How to restrict yum to install or upgrade a package to a fixed specific package version?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/98873)
  This shows how to freeze a package at a given version number.
  This is somewhat the opposite of what you are asking for,
  but may be useful.

Comment: what do you mean by I'm not stuck? since you've said older minor version will not receive ANY updates (even the security ones)

Comment: All updates are available in the CentOS vault. To go from 6.5 to 6.9 you can modify the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and change all paths to point to `baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.9/...`, then do a yum update to reflect the changes.

Comment: what if I just want to upgrade to 6.9 for the name's sake, so I can manually upgrade single package later, rather than upgrade a whole lot of them?

Comment: I mean, what is the difference between 6.5 and 6.9 exactly? apart from the changes in CentOS-Base.repo?

Comment: I can't answer what are the differences, you will have to consult the release notes. It's true that you can manually upgrade one single package and its dependencies at any time using the CentOS vault repo, just as you do with the standard one, except the standard one will not work for you as long as you are not totally updated to the latest minor version minus one.

Comment: @harrymc hold on that's some new information you are bring in here, so you're saying the standard repo will work if I am in the second to lastest minor version?

Comment: No, sorry, I was tired and mis-phrased. You have to be on the latest version in order to get running updates to that version. But upgrading to that version should be easy.

Comment: please, one last request, would you look at my second question? aka 'minimal upgrade'?

Comment: I have added information to my answer.

Comment: if this is the way to properly update software, then why does CentOS limit available software updates from older minor version? why not just let them update to the newest version in newest CentOS minor version?

Comment: The idea to incite you to keep up with the latest updates, or suffer these complexities. In the name of security, of course.

Comment: your statement is very differnet from @PimpJuiceIT's, he believes that CentOS does so because some package updates will not be compatible to older OS minor version.

Comment: My statement is based on some early announcements by CentOS, but there can certainly have been additional design goals added for the final product, not only that of security.